# I want same help for interfacing my C# application with Odoo

Tags: c#, odoo

I have a C# application and I want to relate it with Odoo Database (I want to read from the database and write on it) but I just found in Odoo documentation (connection with Java/Python/PHP and ruby). Can anyone help me with tutorials or documentation to make that connection???

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/iceship/OdooRpcWrapper) connector/wrapper.

You can also refer the REST API mentioned [here](https://odoorestapi.azurewebsites.net/Help). You can also test endpoints there.